# How to reclaim disk space in a SQLDB service instance?

Tags: ibm-cloud, sqldb

I have an instance of a SQLDB Free Plan that I managed to consume all 100 MiB of disk space. Attempts to insert any new data fail with SQLCODE=-289 SQLSTATE=57011, which basically indicates that there is no more disk space.

I dropped all of the tables in the database, and then tried creating a new table. Alas, I still get the SQLCODE=-289 SQLSTATE=57011, even though the database should be empty now.

Some internet research suggests we need to "reclaim" the disk space in the tablespace. So we tried to run this command:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE [tablespace name] reduce max
```

But we get an error that indicates that our user is not authorized to run the ALTER TABLESPACE command.

At this point, the SQLDB instance is completely unusable.

Two questions:

- How can I reclaim the disk space to make the SQLDB instance usable again?
- Will we run into this with a SQLDB Small or Premium instance as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL DB service in the US South region is experiencing some issues right now. 
You can see that in the Bluemix status page here:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

The problems you have may be related to this.
I'd suggest you wait for the service to comeback online again and retry creating the table.

Regards,

Alex.

PS: SQL DB service is back online. You should be able to create new tables.

Comment: I ran into the problem weeks ago, but nonetheless, now that the SQLDB service is back up following the brief outage, I cannot recreate the issue. Deleting the tables effectively clears the disk space.